# Are there any security issues setting `document.domain = document.domain;`?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, xss

I'm hoping to build an application which allows `subdomain.domain.com` to open a popup window at `domain.com` and manipulate that window.

To do this, I need to set `document.domain` to the same value on both the parent and the popup window.

In the popup window, this will be as simple as the following:

```
document.domain = document.domain;
```

This seems harmless to me -- I'll only be allowing cross-site javascript to be run from subdomains. All of my subdomains are -- and always will be -- under my control.

Are there any security issues I'm overlooking from setting `document.domain = document.domain;`?

Thanks for any advice